# How to restore old was profile from filesystem

Tags: websphere, was, wcs

I had some profile in the WebSphere application server but due to some issue i had to re install the WAS. now i want to load that old profile which still exist in my file system. is there any way to get that profile back?

Answer (score 0):

There is a WebSphere feature called swinging profiles that you may find helpful https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=server-swinging-profiles-between-product-installations